# Scheme Programming Language

Tags: scheme

I am trying to write a scheme program, but I am trying to figure out how can i do this:

suppose, I have called a function named addFunc, that takes two input numbers,
computes the sum squares of each number and returns the sum of the two sum
squares

in math, : if addFunc were called with 3 and 2, it will computer the sum squares of 3 as 1*1
+ 2*2 + 3*3 = 14 and sum squares of 2 as 1*1 + 2*2 = 5 and then returns 19 as a
result.

how can i write this in scheme programing language?

Comment: did you try something and it didn't work?  Do you know Scheme?  Did you look at any examples in Scheme?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to add and multiply in scheme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177819/how-to-add-and-multiply-in-scheme)

Comment: possibly, but this one also touches on recursion.

Answer (score 1):

[SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) is a good resource for learning scheme.

```
(define (sum-of-squares x)
  (if (= 1 x)
  1
  (+ (* x x) (sum-of-squares (- x 1)))))

(define (homework x y)
  (+ (sum-of-squares x) (sum-of-squares y)))
```